# Not able to fetch option value text in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have included given code

```
$('#order_bill_address_attributes_country_id').change(function(){
    var countryValue = $(this).val();
    alert(countryValue) #"28"
    var country = $('option[value= countryValue]').text();
    alert(country)

})
```

when i do this it give country nil but when I do

```
$('#order_bill_address_attributes_country_id option[value="28"]').text();
```

it gives me o/p "Jordan". But why its not giving in my above change function. Please guide am a i doing some syntactical mistake.

Comment: `var country = $('option[value="' + countryValue + '"]').text();`

Comment: You can also try `$("#order_bill_address_attributes_country_id option:selected").text();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`:selected`](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) selector

```
var country = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
```

Or, if you still want to use the variable, pass it in quotes

```
var country = $(this).find('option[value="' + countryValue + '"]').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var country = $('option[value= "'+countryValue+"']').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is work for you.

```
$('#order_bill_address_attributes_country_id').change(function(){
    var countryValue = $(this).val();
    alert(countryValue) #"28"
    var country = $("option[value='"+countryValue+"']").text();
    alert(country)

})
```